# Django error NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'add-to-fav-songs' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: django

So I want users to be able to add songs to a section called 'Favorite songs'(just like adding products to a cart in an e-commerce website) but I'm getting this error `NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'add-to-fav-songs' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['add\\-to\\-fav\\-songs/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']`. Can anyone correct my code and show me how can I add songs to `favorite songs`.
Thanks in advance!

My models.py:

```
class Songs(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    lyrics = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    track_image = models.CharField(max_length=2083)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('/', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

My views.py:

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'songs': Songs.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)

@login_required
def add_to_fav_songs(request):
    
    fav_song = get_object_or_404(Songs)

class Fav_songs(ListView):
    model = Songs
    template_name = 'fav_songs.html'
    context_object_name = 'fav_song'
    paginate_by = 2

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Songs.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

My urls.py:

```
path('add-to-fav-songs/<int:pk>/', views.add_to_fav_songs, name='add-to-fav-songs'),
path('favourite-songs/', Fav_songs.as_view(), name='favourite-songs'),
```

My home.html:

```
{% for song in songs %}
  <article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
      
      <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'song-detail' song.id %}">{{ song.title }}</a></h2>
      <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'author-songs' song.author %}">{{ song.author }}</a>
      </div>
      <br>
      <img class="card-img-bottom" height="339px" width="20px" src="{{ song.track_image }}">
    </div>
    <!-- <button> <a href="{% url 'add-to-fav-songs' object.id %}"></a> Add To Favourite Songs</button> -->
    <form class="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'add-to-fav-songs' song.id %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="action">
        <button class="like btn btn-danger" type="button"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </article>
{% endfor %}
```

My fav_songs.html:

```
{% for fav_song in songs %}
  <article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">

      <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'song-detail' song.id %}">{{ fav_song.title }}</a></h2>
      <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'author-songs' song.author %}">{{ fav_song.author }}</a>
      </div>
      <br>
      <img class="card-img-bottom" height="339px" width="20px" src="{{ fav_song.track_image }}">
    </div>
  </article>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you show the view that is rendering `home.html`?

Comment: Yes bro I added it

Comment: @Abrar your home view does not pass any `object` into the context, hence `object.id` is an empty string, is that your complete template for the `home.html`? You must be looping over `songs` right? use the variable you use in that loop.

Comment: I've added my home.html and changed `object.id` to `song.id`, but I am still getting the same error

Comment: @Abrar "Putting something in an HTML comment" != "Django will ignore that and won't try rendering it" Instead of that comment you need to _remove_ that incorrect code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue in your code was that you wrote:

```
{% url 'add-to-fav-songs' object.id %}
```

Here the problem is that there is no variable `object` in the context and hence `object.id` just resolves to an empty string, giving you an error. You need to replace this with `song.id`:

```
{% url 'add-to-fav-songs' song.id %}
```

Next you tried this comment to remove that faulty code:

```
<!-- <button> <a href="{% url 'add-to-fav-songs' object.id %}"></a> Add To Favourite Songs</button> -->
```

Here the problem is that Django does not care about HTML comments, it will try to render them and once again give you the same error. You can either remove this code or use the [`comment` template tag [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#comment) to make Django actually consider it as a comment:

```
{% comment %}
    <button> <a href="{% url 'add-to-fav-songs' object.id %}"></a> Add To Favourite Songs</button>
{% endcomment %}
```